# Running app in vmware by python code?

Tags: python, windows, vmware-workstation

How does running app by python code?i want python code  to run app in the vm-ware.

Is there any way to launch my app from the host machine y python code ?

Comment: You don't run an app in VMware, you run an app in the OS running in the virtual machine running on VMware.

Comment: I have windows in VMware.I know that app running in the os.I want to know how run app in vm-ware (windows) from the host (remotly)by python

Comment: Is there a way to launch a program from the command-line on the host. and if so how is it done (what's the command and arguments)? With that information you should be able to do it.

Comment: From reading the vmware article [**Create Virtual Machine Application Shortcuts on the Host in Unity Mode**](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-02A9FC47-B544-4603-8C1C-9BAF958662C5.html) it sounds like you could do this that "mode". The steps described say it creates a desktop shortcut on the host, so you could examine that afterwards and see what needs to be done to do such a thing.

Comment: thanks but I want to write  connection by python code for example I want run the one app in the vm by python code. I know c++ lib (runprogramhostguest but in the python lib i cant find useful lib.I find  a vix libraryand dont work running program